# Implementation of printf() function

Tags: c, operating-system, osdev

I'm making a hobbyist kernel and I'm trying to implement a `printf()` function.

Here's my implementation:

```
void kprint(uint8_t *format, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, format);

  uint8_t *ptr;

  for (ptr = format; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) {
    if (*ptr == '%') {
      ptr++;
      switch (*ptr) {
        case 's':
          puts(va_arg(ap, uint8_t *), 0x0F, xPos, yPos);
          break;
      }
    } else {
      puts(ptr, 0x0F, xPos, yPos);
      ptr++;
    }
  }

  va_end(ap);
}
```

When I want to print "Hello World!" using this function it returns me that:

```
"Hello %sllo %so %sWorld"
```

Here's function call:

```
kprint("Hello %s", "World");
```

Comment: seems that you're incrementing `ptr` twice when not encountering `%`. Also, don't forget to treat `%%` as `%`

Comment: Have you tried to debug this as part of a simple user mode program?

Comment: also `puts` prints the remaining of the string. You need `putc(*ptr)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I removed pointer incrementing and replaced puts() with putc() in else block, but now it prints only given argument.

Comment: `puts(va_arg(ap, uint8_t *), 0x0F, xPos, yPos);`  that's not going to work. it leaves `xpos` and `ypos` with the wrong (ie unaltered) value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the main issue is that you're using `puts` to print *the rest of the string* instead of current char.

```
 } else {
   puts(ptr, 0x0F, xPos, yPos);
   ptr++;
}
```

also you're incrementing `ptr` when it's already done in the loop. Useful to consume format argument, but not in that case.

A working implementation (not using the strange `puts` prototype) that works on a standard system (tested on windows gcc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void zprintf(uint8_t *format, ...)
  {
      va_list ap;
      va_start(ap, format);

      uint8_t *ptr;

      for (ptr = format; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++) {
          if (*ptr == '%') {
              ptr++;
              switch (*ptr) {
                  case 's':
                      fputs(va_arg(ap, uint8_t *),stdout);
                      break;
                 case '%':
                      putchar('%');
                      break;
              }
             } else {
               putchar(*ptr);

            }
           }

           va_end(ap);
}

int main(){

    zprintf("%% Hello %s\n","World");    
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
% Hello World
```

(as a bonus, this implementation handles the escaped `%` char)

Using only your special implementation of `puts` you could change

```
 } else {
   puts(ptr, 0x0F, xPos, yPos);
   ptr++;
}
```

to a working:

```
 } else {
   char c[2];
   c[0] = *ptr; c[1] = '\0';
   puts(c, 0x0F, xPos, yPos);
 }
```

lame but would work :)

Comment: Yes and it worked. But when I run it in Qemu it doesn't work. I know my prototype is weird, because its arguments specifies also foreground and background color and position on screen where it should be displayed.

Comment: check `putc` prototype on your platform, or create a 2-sized char * with only 1 char in it (eeek)

Comment: It works now. I also changed my puts prototype so it now takes only char. I will still try to do it your way before an edit.

Comment: `puts` appends `'\n'`.  Suggest `fputs(va_arg(ap, uint8_t *), stdout);`

Comment: @chux I implemented puts function myself

Comment: @msk If you made your `puts()` to act like the standard C `puts()`, the issue remains - the `'\n'` should not be added by `"%s"`.  If you made your `puts()` to act differently than the standard C `puts()`, then code is confusing and should use a different name.

Comment: it is sometimes confusing the compilers too when they see those names overriding their builtins. That's the reason I changed to `zprintf`

Answer (score 3):

```
void kprint(char *format, ...) 
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    char *ptr = format;

  while(*ptr)
  {
    if (*ptr == '%') 
    {
      ptr++;
      switch (*ptr++) 
      {
        case 's':
          printf("%s", va_arg(ap, char *));
          break;
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
      putchar(*ptr++);
    }
  }

  va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    kprint("Hello %s World%s", "AAAAA", " BBBBBB");

    return 0;
}
```